# How to use predicate in angular2

Tags: angular, testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have created a login page using `angular2`. It has two input field as `userName` and `password`. And there is a button in that login.
When I'm going to write test case for that `loginComponent`, had to use `predicate` for recognize the `button`. Here is my test case.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';


export class LoginComponentTest {
  constructor(public loginComponent: LoginComponent){
    this.loginComponent.logIn('Chathura', '1234');

  }
}

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
    })
  });

  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

  const button = fixture.query(predicate: Predicate<DebugElement>, scope?: Function) : DebugElement

});
```

I'm gonna test by providing input values then click the login button and look what happen next.

I was unable to find correct tutorial to use predicate correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create a `Predicate` is to use one of the [`By`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/By-class.html) static methods, i.e. `css`, `directive`.

```
const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.the-button')).nativeElement;
```

The `By.css` let's you pass any css selector. The result of the `query` will be a `DebugElement`, so you need to get the `nativeElement` if you want to interact with the native DOM element.

Comment: I know of using `By.css('.the-button')` but the problem is that if there is a set of buttons it is difficult to recognize each and every button. Thats how can we that?. Better if there is a function to call `id`.

Comment: Use need to use the correct selector. You know how to select the particular button using css? This is basic css stuff. Not related to Angular. The `css` method can take any css selector. If you are not sure about how to do it, then you can make it easier and just give the button an id. Then you can just do `css('#button-id')`